# How to use Checker Framework annotations with Findbugs?

Tags: java, guava, findbugs, checker-framework

I am migrating codebase to Guava 26.0-jre from 18.0. Static code checks are processed by Findbugs (3.0.0). It turns out that Guava [migrated from JSR305 to Checker Framework](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/6f22af40e1526b8c194e9e36d457bcd37680c6a3).

Therefore, existing code like this:

```
com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(someCollection, null);
```

ends up with an error:

```
[INFO] Null passed for non-null parameter of com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getFirst(Iterable, Object)
```

My question is: how to force Findbugs to understand Checker Framework's annotations? Is there any way to do this smoothly? I have googled for some plugins for Findbugs but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FindBugs cannot do this.  FindBugs is also an abandoned project.
You might want to consider its successor [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/).
SpotBugs seems to have [support for Checker Framework annotations](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/523).

Comment: It might explain the extraordinary lack of results when googling. Many thanks, I am going to first suppress all errors and prepare a plan for migrating to SpotBugs. Many thanks!